# Find all sets S with $a+b\in S\implies ab\in S$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find all sets $S$ with at least one element such that for any two reals $a$ and $b$ with $a+b\in S$ we have $ab\in S$.

Progress: If $ab\in S$ then $(b-1)a^2,2(b-2)a^2,\cdots$ is also present in the set as we can write $ab=a+(b-1)a,2a+(b-2)a,\cdots{}$.

Comment: Say $a \in S$. Then you have also $a=(\lambda a)+ (1- \lambda)a$, so that $\lambda(1-\lambda)a^2 \in S$ for all real $\lambda$. So you can conclude that $(-\infty , a^2/2] \subseteq S$. Now, use again this argument to conclude that necessarily $S = \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @Crostul: Shouldn't it be $(-\infty,a^2/4] \subseteq S$ as the range of $\lambda(1-\lambda)$ is $(-\infty,1/4]$?

Comment: It probably should be given that $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, otherwise any nonempty $S$ such that $S \cap \mathbb{R} = \emptyset$ fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the fastest, but this does it.

Let $x \in S$. Then, for all $z$, $x = zx + (1-z)x$, so that $z(1-z)x^2  \in S$.

Note that $z(1-z) = y \implies z=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4y}}{2}$, which is  real whenever $y \leq 0.25$. Hence, $S$ certainly must contain $\{yx^2 : y \leq 0.25\}$, which means it contains all negative numbers certainly, and zero.

Now, note that if $x$ is a positive number, then $x = (-\sqrt x) (-\sqrt x)$, where $(-\sqrt x) +  (-\sqrt x) = -2\sqrt x \in S$. Hence, $x \in S$. So $S$ contains the positive and negative numbers (and zero), hence $S = \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

1) $0 \in S$ since $\forall s \in S$, $s + 0 \in S \implies s*0 \in S$.

2) $a<0 \in S$ since $\sqrt{-a}+(-\sqrt{-a}) \in S \implies a \in S$.

3) $a>0 \in S$ since $-\sqrt{a} + -\sqrt{a} \in S \implies a \in S$.

Note that as written (without constraint $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$), $S$ may also contain no real numbers at all (say, $S = \{\{0\}, 2i+17, (x \to 2x^2-6) \}$).

Comment: I would comment this. Saying that $S$ is a set is just to vague.